# XSLT: combining two consecutive elements until element list is empty

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XML

```
<participants>
  <event>Seminar</event>
  <location>City somewhere</location>
  <first_name>Carl</first_name>
  <last_name>Smith</last_name>
  <first_name>John</first_name>
  <last_name>Somebody</last_name>
  <first_name>Lisa</first_name>
  <last_name>Lint</last_name>
  <first_name>Gabriella</first_name>
  <last_name>Whowho</last_name>
</participants>
```

Which I would need to be transformed into this:

```
<participants>
  <event>Seminar</event>
  <location>City somewhere</location>
  <persons>
     <person>
        <given_name>Carl</given_name>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
    </person>
    <person>
        <given_name>John</given_name>
        <surname>Somebody</surname>
    </person>
    <person>
        <given_name>Lisa</given_name>
        <surname>Lint</surname>
    </person>
    <person>
        <given_name>Gabriella</given_name>
        <surname>Whowho</surname>
    </person>
  </persons>
</participants>
```

The number of persons can be any number, sometimes there might be empty elements (if both first and last names would be empty, then the person would not be created.

I have hard time getting started with this transformation.

Comment: In XSLT 2/3 it would be a text book use case for `<xsl:for-each-group select="first_name | last_name" group-starting-with="first_name">` so see any example of that in your favourite XSLT book or tutorial (for instance https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) and try to adapt it and post any problems you have on your way. In XSLT 1 I guess you need to use sibling recursion.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to stick with XSLT 1 :(

Comment: Use sibling recursion or, if there are only these two elements you know by name, the process all `first_name` elements and pull in the `following-sibling::last_name[1]` element.

Comment: @toqmala In future if you require an XSLT 1.0 solution please say so up-front, and tag the question accordingly. The number of people using version 1.0 is on the decline... it's a very old technology.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply process the `first_name` elements and use XPath navigation to select its sibling `last_name` you get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="participants">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::first_name | self::last_name)]"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="first_name" mode="person"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="first_name" mode="person">
      <xsl:variable name="surname" select="following-sibling::last_name[1]"/>
      <xsl:if test="normalize-space() and normalize-space($surname)">
          <person>
              <xsl:apply-templates select=". | $surname"/>
          </person>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="first_name">
      <given_name>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </given_name>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="last_name">
      <surname>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </surname>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAW/1

Comment: @toqmala, if there are still problems then consider to post them in a new, separate question with well-formatted code samples or at least edit your question and show any code sample there in a well-formatted way, don't expect us to read XML markup in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to, got grabbed by a coworker and didn't have time to return to edit till now. I will remove and repost. Thank you